# How to enrich the Django request object with extended functions?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-request

In my Django project, I have a situation where different views communicate via a request session data as follows:

```
def view_one(request):
    ...
    request.session['my_session_key'] = data
    ...

def view_two(request):
    ...
    data = request.session['my_session_key']
    ...
```

However, this has the following problems:

- The key string `my_session_key` is not a constant so it will be hard to scale it up to other parts of the code if I start writing to and/or reading from it in other parts of my code.
- As this system grows, it will become harder to identify which are the available keys being used and written in the session.

In Kotlin (which I'm more familiar with), one way to solve this would be using an extension function, like so:

```
var Request.my_session_key: Int
  get() = this.session['my_session_key']
  set(value) { this.session['my_session_key'] = value }
```

This way, I could now write my views as follows:

```
def view_one(request):
    ...
    request.my_session_key = data
    ...

def view_two(request):
    ...
    data = request.my_session_key
    ...
```

Is there any way to accomplish something similar in Python or with Django? Or, alternatively, taking a step back, what would be the best way to organize the data stored in a Django session across multiple views?